# JQuery - How to stop previous function executions or reset setTimeout() timer

Tags: jquery

Overall idea is following - every time button is pressed a function is called with delay of 2 seconds. Can I stop previous function timer with new funciton call - when button is pressed one more time?

For example.

```
<script>
    $('#button').click(function() {
        //some logic here
        setTimeout(DoSomeOtherLogic, 2000);
    });

    function DoSomeOtherLogic() {
        //some other logic
    }
</script>
<div id="button">Button</div>
```

So if I press "Button" five times - five functions with delay of 2 seconds will be called. But the idea is that it should execute only once when I stop pressing "Button". Meaning every time button is pressed - it resets delay timer.

Is it possible?

updated: removed `()` from setTimeout() call in example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use global software switches like the following example to make it work fine. Or try it by using `clearTimeout()` before every new `setTimeout` (But using `clearTimeout` will not indicate, that your function is finished -> it can be called more than once at the same time so.).

**This solution is much cleaner because:**

This solution is much cleaner (yes, more code). But it ensures that the logic part in the called function is done after the next "click" is incoming. `clearTimeout` dont do that. By using `clearTimeout` -> it just clear a running timeout. Once the function is called (which probably will run a few seconds) the user will be able to click the button again, which will trigger a new timeout (while function code is not finished!). ***The following solution ensures the called function after timeout is finished before starting another timeout.***

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var globalState = false;

    $('#button').click(function() {
        //some logic here
        if (!globalState) {
           globalState = true;
           setTimeout(DoSomeOtherLogic, 2000);
        }
    });

    function DoSomeOtherLogic() {

        //some other logic

        //reset switch after logic is done
        globalState = false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, my solution is much cleaner (yes, more code). But it ensures that the logic part in the called function is done after the next "click" is incoming. `clearTimeout` dont do that. It just clear a `running` timeout. Once the function is called (which probably will run a few seconds) the user will be able to click the button again, which will indicate a new timeout (while function code is not finished!).

Comment: @lin OP didn't mention any async operation in `DoSomeOtherLogic()`

Comment: Right, but maybe this solution will help some people who exactly want this behavior.

Comment: @lin Ya i see in some specific cases, this could be a better solution

Comment: Btw. this is the question `How to stop previous function executions or reset setTimeout() timer`

Comment: @lin Anyway, i'd find better to disable button and renable it once function is done. Regarding UI, this would really be better imho

Answer (score 4):

(It should be: `setTimeout(myFunction, 2000);` without the `()`  )

## Click : subsequent click only available after 2s

```
$('#button').one("click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
    setTimeout(function(){
       console.log("TESSSST");
       $('#button').one("click", myFunction);
    }, 2000);
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/one/

## Click : clear previous timeout (restarts the 2s timeout)

```
var myTimeout;

$('#button').click(function() {
    clearTimeout( myTimeout );
    myTimeout = setTimeout(myFunction, 2000);
});

function myFunction() {
    console.log("TESSSST");
}
```

Comment: Just out of curisioty, will `clearTimeout` return silently with `myTimeout` is undefined?

Comment: Sorry for misleading - original function had a parameter.

Comment: @user3725355 if your functio ncall has arguments than use it inside the timeout function callback as a new function call.

Comment: Roko C. Buljan storing timeout into a variable didn't help - function is still called for every time button is pressed. Passing it to clearTimeout looks like also didn't help - still checking.

Comment: @user3725355  Test here, press 10 times the button, it'll yield in console only once. http://jsbin.com/wacike/2/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: @AndréPena Yes it will

Comment: Roko C. Buljan problem was in parameters passed. It works good. Thanks.

Comment: But what to do if I need to pass a parameter to function?

Comment: @user3725355 wrap it in anonymous function: `setTimeout(function(){DoSomeOtherLogic(param);}, 2000);`

Comment: Sorry, this doesnt answer the question. Its not about finishing a timer, its about ensure that the function is not called twice while its not finished. Check my Solution.

Comment: @user3725355 had no time to edit my answer (back from lunch :) ) take a look.